# My C language program is giving a random space at the start and also generating one more serial number at the end

Tags: c, file, io

The program generates a blank space at the first line of the "data.txt" file and also generates a one more serial number.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    
    int main(){
        int limit;
        int i = 0;
        printf("How many approxmiate size of your list will be: \n");
        scanf("%d", &limit);
        char list[100][100];
         
        
        FILE *store;
        store = fopen("data.txt", "w");
        while(i<=(limit - 1)){
            printf("Enter task: \n");
            gets(list[i]);
            fprintf(store,"%s\n%d)",list[i], i+1); 
            i++;
        }
    
        fclose(store);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: As a side note: `gets()` is dangerous and shouldn't be used, read the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer , thank you for the tip but the problem is in the while loop where is prints one empty character in the first line and also prints an extra serial number at the end

Comment: It's not very clear what you're saying the problem is. A (very short) example of the input given to the program and the resulting file contents would help.

Comment: I remain baffled by the practice of reading parameters from stdin.  `int main(int argc, char **argv) { int limit = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1; ...`

Comment: And `while(i<=(limit - 1))` is much easier to read and understand as `while(i < limit)` or even better as `for ( int = 0; i < limit; i++ )`.

Comment: gets remained an official part of the language up to the 1999 ISO C standard, but it was officially deprecated by the 2011 standard and removed in the 2014 standard. Most C implementations still support it, but at least gcc issues a warning for any code that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the linefeed (`'\n'`) after `scanf("%d", &limit);` remains in the input buffer, either change `scanf("%d", &limit);` to `scanf("%d ", &limit);` or better yet, *don't* use `gets()` at all (it's dangerous to use `gets()`: read the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)), instead use `fgets()` or `scanf()`.

So your final code may look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    int limit;
    int i = 0;
    printf("How many approxmiate size of your list will be: \n");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    char list[100][100];
     
    
    FILE *store;
    store = fopen("data.txt", "w");
    while(i<=(limit - 1)){
        printf("Enter task: \n");
        scanf(" %99[^\n]",list[i]);
        fprintf(store,"%s\n%d)",list[i], i+1); 
        i++;
    }

    fclose(store);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: `scanf("%99s",list[i]);` fails to read input like `"Hello World"` as one line of input.

Comment: `scanf(" %99[^\n]",list[i]);` has its troubles too (e.g. `"\n"`), but not the main point for OP.